# Unix Output file content to a variable

Tags: file, variables, unix

I need to read the contents of a text file and assign the content to  variable to be available in the script. I see many questions on the same topic but my script does not work.

```
export CONTENT_FROM_FILE="/home/me/test.sql"
echo $CONTENT_FROM_FILE
VAR=$(while IFS= read line;do echo "$line";done < "$CONTENT_FROM_FILE")
echo $VAR
```

This gives the error "No such File or directory". So i did the following,

```
VAR=$(while IFS= read line;do echo "$line";done < "/home/me/test.sql")
echo $VAR
```

In this case, its able to read the file but echo $VAR prints only the portion of the file.

Comment: That's really strange. `CONTENT_FROM_FILE` should work even without `export` statement, and your code works for me perfectly (that is, if you intend to read the whole file in one line). Could you give an example of file for which it fails, and the output you're getting?

Comment: @learninghuman: Do provide feedback on the provided answers to help you out further. Or alternatively, if it helped solve your problem, do accept/up-vote the answer for it to be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in `bash`, you can do [`command-substitution`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) to achieve the same and avoid use of `cat` or a redundant `while-loop`

```
#!/bin/bash
myFileContent="$(<myFile)"  #  Sets "myFileContent" to contents of "myFile".
```

To see this in action, am filling a sample file with below contents:-

```
$ cat file
Hi This is a test file - First line
Hi This is a test file - Second line

Hi This is a test file - Third line
```

Am running a script which reads this file and prints it to `stdout`

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
myfileContent="$(<file)"

echo "$myfileContent"
```

On running the script as

```
$ ./script.sh
Hi This is a test file - First line
Hi This is a test file - Second line

Hi This is a test file - Third line
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpliesy way is

> VAR=`cat myfile`